# How to access marker added to node in py.test framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I am adding a marker to node with node.add_marker, is there any way to fetch the marker value from node, so that I can make sure that whatever I am setting up, is actually begin set up or not.

When I try to access node, it just gives me a reference to the function where the node is pointing to, what I want is to print the marker which I am adding to node.

```
(Pdb++) node.add_marker(pytest.mark.mymarker(myoption='yes'))
(Pdb++) node
<Function 'test_1'>
```

Can someone help me in figuring out the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a `get_marker()` method you can call with the string name of the marker, so in your example I would try `node.get_marker('mymarker')`.

In general, since you have access to a python shell with some objects you want to inspect, you can use the `dir()` function to list properties of an object, e.g. `dir(node)` to see what properties it has. Another trick I use is looking at `node.__dict__` since many objects use that internal property.

Note also that that "node" variable is of type `Function`, which is one of pytest's classes for doing the magic it does. Reading [the source code](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/python.py#L1548) is another way of figuring out what you can do with that object.